# CSS styling not applying

Tags: html, css

sorry for the dumb question, but I can't figure out why my css code is not being applied? I do have the css file in the same folder and I did right it correctly. It works for some pages, but this but won't apply no matter what.

CSS code

```
  ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

Page:

```
<nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../admin/view.php?uname=<?php echo $_SESSION['AdminUser']; ?>">Manage users</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../class.php?uname=<?php echo $_SESSION['AdminUser']; ?>">Manage classes</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="../logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../changepassword.php">Change password</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

EDIT: I have changed it according to the comments below, and tried to open it in Firefox. For some reason, the CSS code works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `a.active` or `a:active` ?

Comment: What part of it is not applying? Unrelated to your question, but a couple other tips from things i noticed in your code: `link` elements no longer need the `type` attribute for stylesheets and it is [best practice to not include them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-type). Your menu element should probably be a `<nav>` not a `div`, and inside it you use `<ul>` element with all links inside `<li>` elements. Then remove the <br> elements which should not be used anymore. [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav#Examples)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4spahtdo/) with your code, but it behaves the same way in both browsers.

Comment: Or maybe it's just a caching problem. Clear the browser cache and reload.

Comment: @MrLister I cleared the cache and now it works perfectly. Thank you.